# Scanning for Java executable

Tags: c#, file, for-loop, directory

I'd like my program to scan the user's hard drive for java.exe.

I was considering using a for-loop and then going through each directory and then check if the directory names match the ones I would set up and then check in those for the java exe, but I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of doing so.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Edit:

I've gone ahead and done some foreach loops, but it isn't going too well. I'm probably missing something:

```
// Scan for Java executable (java.exe)
        foreach (String dir in Directory.GetDirectories("C:/"))
        {
            if (dir == "Program Files")
            {
                foreach (String _dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir)) {
                    if (_dir == "Java")
                    {
                        foreach (String javaDir in Directory.GetDirectories(_dir))
                        {
                            if (javaDir == "jre7")
                            {
                                foreach (String binDir in Directory.GetDirectories(javaDir)) {
                                    if (binDir == "bin")
                                    {
                                        foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(binDir))
                                        {
                                            if (file == "java.exe")
                                            {
                                                javaExe = file;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the end game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for java.exe. So
Firstly you should look for directory where [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/index.html) always install it's java.exe
which should be at

> C:\Windows\System32

to limit your search and then search in other directories.

```
         var paths = new List<string>
        {
           Environment.SystemDirectory,
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)+@"\java",
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)+@"\java",
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)+@"\java"
           //C:\
           //rest
        };
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            var ser = Search("java.exe", path);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ser))
            {
                if (File.Exists(ser))
                {
                    javaExe = ser;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Search function:

```
 private static string Search(string pattern, string root)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var paths = new Queue<string>();
        paths.Enqueue(root);
        while (paths.Count > 0)
        {
            root = paths.Dequeue();
            string[] temp = Directory.GetFiles(root, pattern);
            foreach (string t in temp)
            {
                return t;
            }
            temp = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
            foreach (string t in temp)
            {
                paths.Enqueue(t);
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Also it's preferred to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles) search method to avoid Access permissions.

**Note:**
You could find java.exe in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want to see if `java.exe` is there?

```
File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe")
```

You might need additional logic to look in the `Program Files (x86)` folder if needed. Also this will obviously fail if the user installed java somewhere else.

If you want to know where is java, take a look at [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038140/how-to-determine-windows-java-installation-location).