# Issue with The System cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with "The System cannot find the file specified"

Here is the part of my code that fails:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", javaParam + " -jar " + jar)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            WorkingDirectory = _diretory
        };

        Process = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo };
        Process.Start();
```

In this image. you can see "Arguments" and "WorkingDirectory". my "craftbukkit.jar" is in my working directory. But It can't find it.
[locals http://bumisworld.eu/locals.png](http://bumisworld.eu/locals.png)

And here is the error when I run it outside Visual Studio..

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at The_Bukkit_GUI_Project.MinecraftProcess.StartProcess()
   at The_Bukkit_GUI_Project.Form1.Start()
   at The_Bukkit_GUI_Project.Form1.load_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonBase.buttonElement_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonElement.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.DoClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DoMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentInputBehavior.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

But for some reason. This works on my local computer. But this happens on my remote server. And I have no idea why.. So I'm looking for a little help..

Comment: Have you tried using the full filename with extension?

Comment: Are you sure the remote server has the same directory layout? How is the _diretory variable filled?

Comment: @Me.Name It is getting filled correctly. If you look at my image. "WorkingDirectory" is 100% correct. To where it need to be.

Comment: And when the program is run on the remote server, it is done so under the Administrator account?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that Java has been installed on the server. Then you should check the following:

If you start a process, it looks for the file name both in the working directory and in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Chances are good that on your developer machine the Java-directory has been added to the `PATH` variable for convinience.

Instead of assigning just `java` as the executable path, a more stable way is to provide the full path of the executable you want to start.

A - less clean - way to fix this quickly is to change the `PATH` variable on the server so that the Java-directory is also contained. Nevertheless I'd propose to reference the executable by its full path so that you don't have to change the `PATH` variable on each computer you want to run your program on.

Comment: Java is installed. When I run "java -jar craftbukkit.jar" from a bat file. It runs fine. And I have tried that with PATH. I got a bit of code getting the location from path. But still no luck with that.

Comment: @StianTofte: can you try to reference both Java and the jar in your code with a full path, maybe first Java, then the jar to find out which one is the reason?

Comment: Well It was Java that it couldn't find for some reason.. When I put the full path to "java.exe". It worked. But now I guess I will have to find a new way to locate java..

Comment: @StianTofte: maybe this question and its answers help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038140/how-to-determine-windows-java-installation-location