# Get Java installation location on Win10

Tags: c#, .net, registry, .net-4.6

I’m trying to get the java installation location on Windows 10 with C# (.NET 4.6). I tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038526/3366090 but it doesn’t work for me on windows 10. 
The Environment variable **is not set** and the registry solution isn't working either. I can follow the registry tree down to

> “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft”

BUT

> “Java Runtime Environment”

always returns **null**. I checked it twice with regedit and the “Java Runtime Environment” registry folder exists and is filled with the installed java versions.

Btw: Same solution is working on win7,8,8.1 without any issues :/

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Looks like "OpenSubKey" can't open registry tree folders which include spaces. Tried some different folders with the same result.

Comment: Why is the env variable not set?

Comment: @JamesBlond I don't know. Checked 10 (different) Windows 10 PC's and the env isn't set. I guess the env will net set on default installation of JAVA