# i want to execute a precompiled java class file from a MVC action.the class file is placed with in the C# project folder.

Tags: java, c#

i want to execute a precompiled java class file from a MVC action.the class file is placed with in the C# project folder. But Still it throws File Not Found Exception.

`Process myProcess = new Process();

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//File not Found Exception Appears Here
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"java JDKTest2";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();`
```

Comment: You need to make sure your path to the java.exe is specified correctly see if  [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038140/how-to-determine-windows-java-installation-location) helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to pack java class to a jar and call it like this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//File not Found Exception Appears Here
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar JDKTest2.jar";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

Also make sure the paths to `java` and `JDKTest2.jar` are known in this context or switch to absolute path.

Comment: it worked ! but now the process returns exit code 1.

Comment: I am Working on a java Online compiler as semester project ! I created a similar application in java servlets ! which works fine ! but in MVC c# I am barely able to run a jar.